# Any potential problems storing a new in box refrigerator long term

Tags: refrigerator, storage, damage, temperature, pressure

We are having a new house build that is scheduled to be done in about 9 months. We need to purchase a Fridge for the new house and have been keeping an eye on sales to save money.

My question is if we purchase a new fridge and store it in a detached non climate controlled garage are there potential issues and/or damage that may result from outside temperatures as low 0F and as high as 110F? My main concern is that if i recall the refrigerant is under pressure and high temperatures may cause higher pressure to build up and damage gaskets and seals.

Comment: you may have problems with warranty ... out-of-box failure that happens 9 months after purchase may not be covered

Comment: Almost certainly the warranty will be from "when delivered" or "when purchased" depending on your local rules ..  so as long as you are happy with "N" months less ..  When the fridge ships from the manufacturer (say from China) - it is in hot temperatures (less likely really cold) for some number of weeks ...

Comment: The warranty starts on delivery, you don’t want to waste it today!!! Things are not built to last especially if made where most fridges are, just saying.

Comment: Physically it will be fine, they are stored and shipped in more extreme conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wise to ask this with these temp extremes however the timeline is a bigger issue!

Yes there are multiple issues. First your warranty will be almost gone prior to plugging it in and as someone that has fixed brand new hvacR equipment I would look into purchasing at the sale price but on layaway and pay it off and pick it up when the home is done.

I do not know if this can be done but today’s refrigerators are let’s be nice and say “crap”.

Compared to 20 year old units and those were the same for 40 year older units ok that was R12 an Ozone killer but quality was still something mint just making it past warranty!

unless you purchase 10k built in units and that can be 10k for the fridge and freezer no ice maker.

Ice maker failures and water filter leaks that never really get fixed until the warranty has expired tends to be a common issue today.

Check out the layaway program! Don’t waste a minute of the warranty as well things are not made to last and lately I would say things are not made to last beyond the warranty.

No one knows the temp extremes this will go through in storage or will ever know,,,
But when you install your brand new fridge in your new new house and it fails in less than 100 days in many cases, it’s all on you your warranty is over,,,

Ok the warranty is not over but 2nd year they will pay 59.89$ for the failed ice maker if installed by a factory authorized person that charges 3x that amount or close,,,

Don’t ask me how I know and why.